# Angular 4 mixed with React

Tags: angular, reactjs

We are evaluating which front-end framework to pick for our enterprise web app. The current choices are Angular 4 and React.

I saw someone mixed the two here https://github.com/jesion/angular2-react

My question are as follows:

1. Is it a good idea to mix Angular 4 with React? What are the advantages and disadvantages of doing this?
2. Is there any performance benefit for using React as view template and make it into Angular component 'templateUrl'?

Comment: The disadvantage is that you're using two frameworks and have to deal with the interop. React isn't just view templating. IMO mixing the two is a silly idea; in general if you're mixing the two it's because you need to consume React components in an Angular app.

Comment: In any case, I'm not convinced the question is OT for SO.

Comment: @DaveNewton I agree with the part that you said this: *"IMO mixing the two is a silly idea..."*, however I really disagree with that part: *"The disadvantage is that you're using two frameworks..."*. Well, in addition to having many articles saying that React is a library, not a framework, the [**oficial page**](https://facebook.github.io/react/) refers to **React** as a **library for building UI interfaces**.

Comment: @developer033 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ I don't find the distinction meaningful in this case.

Comment: I'm just commenting your comment :) React (according to many sources, including the official) isn't a framework as you said :D

Answer (score 8):

I see the following advantages of combining the two:

- Teams can partially choose their own technology stack.
  That's an important aspect of autonomous teams that have ownership ([see Spotify engineering culture](https://labs.spotify.com/2014/03/27/spotify-engineering-culture-part-1/)). It plays nice with the microservices principle as well (in terms of code split up) Developers are more likely to be extra motivated when they can use their technology of preference.
- Another advantage is that you can share components in non-angular projects, and also non-react projects. React components can be used in angular applications (and other applications), but it's much harder/impossible to use angular components in a react application.

That being said, if you want to create a big Angular project, I would use angular completely and ditch React, but that's a personal preference.
I like the idea when you commit to a framework, that you use it to the fullest.
I don't see React as a framework either, since it's meant to be the view-layer only.

I hope that answers your question